# Почему я не могу рекурсивно прочитать файлы и папки?

Tags: android

Вот кусок кода.
Просто проверяю существует ли папка. Она существует. Но я постоянно получаю False. Почему?

```
File root_dir = new File("/WhatsApp");
if(root.exists()){
   Log.d("","Whatsapp folder exists");
}
```

Comment: Не та переменная?

Comment: При чём тут рекурсия, в заголовке вашего вопроса?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что этой папки не должно быть в корне файловой системы. Скорее всего она у Вас в корне SDCard и тогда путь нужно указать так:

```
    File root_dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "WhatsApp");
    if(root_dir.exists()){
        Log.d("","Whatsapp folder exists");
    }
```

Comment: Карты в телефоне нет. А сама структура папок меняется от устройства к устройству или она всегда фиксированная?

Comment: А тогда где у Вас папка "WhatsApp"? Карта памяти может быть встроенной(несъёмной). А вот насчёт структуры... должна быть одинаковая, но производители аппаратов любят выпендриться всяк по-своему

Comment: Спасибо за решение.